# my bullet wont move after first shot why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a problem with my bullet firing logic.

The first time everything works fine, but when I shoot the bullet after respawning it doesn't move. It only works for the first shot.

The bullet is a prefab.

Here is my code:

```
public Rigidbody2D bulletrb;
private float dirX=1;
public float speed=.001f;
public  Transform playerPos;
private Vector3 bulletPos;
public GameObject bulletObj;

void Update () {
    bulletPos.x = playerPos.transform.position.x + 2;
    bulletPos.y = playerPos.transform.position.y + 1;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
    {
        bulletrb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * speed, bulletrb.velocity.y);
        Debug.Log("Shoot!");
    }
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
{
    if(target.gameObject.tag=="Zombie")
    {
        Destroy(bulletObj);
        Debug.Log("Hited!");
        Instantiate(bulletObj,bulletPos,Quaternion.identity,playerPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Destroy`, you are losing your active bullet `GameObject`, but when you call `Instantiate`, it is not actually assigned back to your `bulletObj` reference.

The quick and simple fix is:

```
bulletObj = Instantiate(bulletObj, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity, playerPos);
```

There are probably more improvements that could be made, but this is the gist of the issue.

---

One recommendation I would make is using `bulletObj.SetActive(false)` and `bulletObj.SetActive(true)` instead of `Destroy` and `Instantiate`

Comment: thanks the bulletObj.SetActive(false) is fixed the issue.